# WAP Push Message Routing Service

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, windows-services

Can you, please, share some knowledge about the Windows 10 service mentioned in the title?

1. Is it only a spying service or there are some other uses for developers/users?
2. What exactly WAP means? Is the reference to the well known [mobile techonlogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Application_Protocol#WAP_Push) to push content on headsets only coincidental?

Comment: Not sure exactly but the Unified Write Filter (Win10 Enterprise) doesn't work when I disable that service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft says](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/windows-services/security-guidelines-for-disabling-system-services-in-windows-server#dmwappushsvc):

> Service required on client devices for Intune, MDM and similar management technologies, and for Unified Write Filter. Not needed for Server.

MDM means Mobile Device Management.

The full name appears to be “Device Management Wireless Application Protocol (WAP) Push Message Routing Service”.

[Further research](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/wcd/wcd-devicemanagement) reveals that Windows 10 supports [“OMA Device Management”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMA_Device_Management). WAP Push can be used to initiate communication with the management service. It’s probably primarily for Windows tablet devices with mobile (3G/4G) connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

WAP Push messages are specially formatted SMS messages that display an alert message to the user, and give the user the option of connecting directly to a particular URL via the mobile phone’s WAP browser.