# Service "dmwappushsvc" in Windows 10 (other service name)

Tags: windows-10, services

When we click Win + R, type *services.msc*, we have various local services in the list.

In Windows 10, I am looking for a service called "dmwappushsvc". Unfortunately, I did not find this service under that name, but it may appear under a different name - below I gave the long/full name:

**Device Management Wireless Application Protocol (WAP) Push message Routing Service**

Is it 100% the same service known as "dmwappushsvc"?

Comment: `sc getkeyname "Device Management Wireless Application Protocol (WAP) Push message Routing Service"` will return `Name = dmwappushservice` which is also the name of its' key in the registry.

Comment: Is this service "Device Management Wireless Application Protocol (WAP) Push message Routing Service" to disable telemetry in Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

The device name is `dmwappushservice` (not `dmwappushsvc`).

Its display-name is "Device Management Wireless Application Protocol
(WAP) Push message Routing Service".

Its Description is:

> Routes Wireless Application Protocol (WAP) Push messages received by the device and synchronizes Device Management sessions

[image]

Comment: Is this service "Device Management Wireless Application Protocol (WAP) Push message Routing Service" to disable telemetry in Windows 10?

Comment: Not all all - see [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1182936/wap-push-message-routing-service).

Comment: Thank you so much for help.